# Why the behaviour of tryCatch doesn't coincide in Rstudio and Jupyter with R Kernel?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, try-catch, jupyter-irkernel

Running following code snippet in R or Rstudio provides following result

```
data <- NULL

data <- tryCatch(
  data.frame(t(data), row.names = NULL),
  error=function(e){
    warning(e)
    warning("NAs returned")
    NA
  }
)

> data
[1] NA
```

where jupyter notebook with R Kernel doesn't wrap the `t(data)` with `tryCatch()`

```
data <- NULL

data <- tryCatch(
  data.frame(t(data), row.names = NULL),
  error=function(e){
    warning(e)
    warning("NAs returned")
    NA
  }
)

Error in t.default(data): argument is not a matrix
Traceback:

1. tryCatch(data.frame(t(data), row.names = NULL), error = function(e) {
 .     warning(e)
 .     warning("NAs returned")
 .     NA
 . })
2. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
3. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
4. value[[3L]](cond)
5. warning(e)   # at line 6 of file <text>
6. withRestarts({
 .     .Internal(.signalCondition(cond, message, call))
 .     .Internal(.dfltWarn(message, call))
 . }, muffleWarning = function() NULL)
7. withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
```

It would be great if someone has an idea?

Thanks
Kateryna

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a IRkernel bug.

https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/646